# Bash regex to replace everything between two different strings

Tags: regex, bash

I want to replace everything between `#Start wp conf` and `#End wp conf` from :

```
#Start wp conf
<Directory "/home/user/public_html/">
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</Directory>
#End wp conf
```

I tried `sed -i -e "s/#Start wp conf.*#End wp conf//g" /root/test-conf` but it did not replace anything.

I also tried `sed -i -e "s/\(#Start wp conf\).*\(#End wp conf\)//g" /root/test-conf`

Comment: "Replace" or "delete"?

Comment: The `s///` operator processes just one line, it can't match across multiple lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed` you can do this:

```
sed '/#Start wp conf/,/#End wp conf/d' file
```